# Should I use Poisson or Binomial distribution to solve this question?

Tags: distributions, binomial-distribution, poisson-distribution

My question goes as below:

A major warehouse facility has 10 semi-trailer loading bays, which can all be used simultaneously. On average only 7 bays are in use.

a. What is the probability that all bays will be in simultaneous use.

b. What is the probability that one or more semi-trailers will have to wait for a bay to become available.

c. Show a loading bay demand for zero to fifteen semitrailers.

Please suggest which distribution **Binomial or Poisson** to use for this question?

Comment: There isn't enough information given to answer this question: you will need to make some additional assumptions.  An example is you might want to assume all bays are equally likely to be used and usage of one bay is independent of usage of any other bay.  For (b) and (c) you will need to assume some kind of stochastic process for the arrivals of semitrailers.